# Django: How to change the user view on the admin site?

Tags: django, view, admin

I'm new in Django, so I have a question about the admin site. I want to modify the user view. I want add some buttons(e.g. "activate") or links in the User-table. But I cannot find any script, where I could modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested augmenting the behavior of the Django Users model as well? If it's just modifying the presentation in the admin area, have a look at the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). The admin UI is customized by adding an admin.py file to your application and referencing the ModelAdmin class. From the docs:

> For each of those models, optionally create a ModelAdmin class that encapsulates the customized admin functionality and options for that particular model.

Comment: yes, I know this documentation, but I would like to modify a django-intern module auth(django.contrib.auth). If I change some settings in auth.admin it changes only the view where you can change the fields of one User. I want to modify the view, where you can see all user(under the url localhost:8000/admin/auth/user). Is it also possible with the ModelAdmin-class?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons and links sound like it can be done in the template. You may want to override add_form.html which renders the User form but you need to have this hierarchy in your templates directory

```
templates/
    admin/
        auth/
            user/
                add_form.html
```

This form extends "admin/change_form.html". For your reference, check out the actual code [online](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/add_form.html).

Comment: thanks. I'll take a look at this template, but it looks promising so far.